# Linq 2 Entities: Subquery based on query result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, subquery

I moved from Linq 2 SQL to Linq 2 Entities due to performance reasons for complex queries.
It's a little bit frustrating to get everything working.

In L2SQL I can run subqueries without any problems.
Now I figured out, that in L2E I have to place the subquery outside the query.

That's usually no problem, but how can I run a query if the subquery depends on the query?

For example:
I want to get the status of an document but for that I need the current documentID.

```
var query = from Dok in dbContext.Dokumente
    orderby Dok.DokumentID descending
    select new ClassDok() {
        _Nr = Dok.Dokumentnr,
        _StatusID = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>("GetDokStatusID", Dok.DokumentID).Single()
    };
```

I already tried to put 
`dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>("GetDokStatusID", Dok.DokumentID).Single()`
into a method and return integer, but it doesn't work.

Comment: there is no way to avoid Stored Procedure `GetDokStatusID`? It would be a good idea to fetch all statuses with one query after you get document result and then just merge statuses with the documents. Otherwise you would DDOS your SQL server with the sub queries.

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir I solved it by removing the stored procedure and put the logic behind  _StatusID =